# Sending vector of int vectors through OpenMPI

Tags: c++, vector, openmpi

I have set up a vector of 2 int vectors and now I want to send it and receive it through OpenMPI so that I can make computations over this structure on slave nodes. If possible, I want to send this bulky structure in one go...

On main, I have declared my vector and made it common to both send and receive sides:

```
std::vector < std::vector<int> > temp;
```

On the sending side, I have filled this structure and later, I have tried to send it:

```
MPI_Send(&temp[0], 2, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

And, on the receiving side, I have been performing:

```
temp.resize(2);
MPI_Recv(&temp[0], 2, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

However, the receiving side is throwing a seg fault as soon as I try to access the received item, so I must be doing something wrong. My questions are what is wrong with this approach, or if it is possible at all or even better if there is a more efficient way to do it!?

Furthermore, I prefer not to use boost so I can better grasp what is going on at this level.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send an array of vectors. A vector is like a pointer to a dynamically allocated array. You're copying a pointer (or whatever appears first in the memory layout of a vector) into the receiving vector's array, then trying to acces the address (but that address refers to memory allocated in the sender).

With two vectors there'll be ints in two places, `&v1[0]` and `&v2[0]` (or `v1.data()` in C++11). If you resize the vector properly you can memcpy an array of ints within one vector into another, but in any case you'll have to do one send operation per vector (i.e. per actual int array).

---

edit: If you're not comfortable with all of this, just copy everything (the two vector's sizes and contents) into one big `int[]` C-style array. Local copying is unlikely to be expensive compared to the actual send.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping there was a way but I guess not. Would you happen to know if it's possible to send so much data in one go?

Comment: It's not a matter of how much data. The problem is that `temp[0].data()` and `temp[1].data()` (both `int*`) point to totally distinct memory blocks.

Comment: I understand, thanks. But I wanted to ask if it's possible that I can still provide this data in one go, perhaps by using another structure or set up, so that I do not have to break my send requests into smaller pieces.

Comment: Well, you can concatenate your two vectors into one

Comment: Sounds a bit dirty but I suppose it's something to think about.

Comment: you can create a derived datatype and use it to send/receive in one shot. note you need to know the two vector sizes on the receiver side when creating the derived datatype (e.g. **before** calling `MPI_Recv()`). this is a bit convoluted and i am not sure the performance gain (if any) is worth the extra complexity. bottom line, sticking to two MPI calls might be a lesser evil.

Comment: @Zeruno, I second Gilles. While possible to define a derived structure datatype with either absolute or relative offsets (see `MPI_Type_create_struct`), the added complexity is just not worth it. In the end, you will still need to send two messages unless the receiver has prior knowledge of the number of vectors and of their sizes.